# Como diferenciar entre un click con el botón derecho o el izquiedo con jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5

Tengo un contador que va sumando los clicks que hago con el boton izquierdo, pero quiero que reste los clicks hechos con el botón derecho. Mi problema es que si utilizo mousedown  con la propiedad which, no distingue los clics y me los cuenta todos iguales. Micódigo es

```
introducir el código aquí

     <nav>
       <div id="comptador1" class="caixa"></div> <br /><br /><br />

       <input type="button" value="Clica aquí" id="boto1" class="boto" /> 
     </nav>

introducir el código aquí

    <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script >
   
     num=0    
     ($("#boto1").mousedown(function(e){
       if(e.which == 1);         
        num++;
       $("#comptador1 ").html('<p>Has clicat '+num1+' vegades</p>');
       if(e.which !== 1);
        num--;
        $("#comptador1 ").html('<p>El botó dret resta '+num+' vegades</p>');
  }))
     </script>
```

Comment: oncontextmenu es lo que buscas

Answer (score 7):

Tienes grandes problemas de sintaxis en tu **Javascript** que ocasionan que tus condiciones no sean funcionales.

Analicemos tu código:

```
if(e.which == 1);         
num++;
$("#comptador1 ").html('<p>Has clicat '+num1+' vegades</p>');
if(e.which !== 1);
num--;
$("#comptador1 ").html('<p>El botó dret resta '+num+' vegades</p>');
```

- La **primera** línea establece una condición pero no afecta a nada, ya que la estás cerrando seguidamente.
- La **segunda** línea, al no depender de condiciones siempre va a aumentar la variable `num` en uno.
- La **tercera** línea siempre va a modificar el **HTML** de `#comptador1`  (has dejado un espacio en blanco detrás del **ID** que deberías evitar).
- La **cuarta** línea establece una condición pero no afecta a nada, ya que la estás cerrando seguidamente.
- La **quinta** línea, al no depender de condiciones siempre va a decrementar la variable `num` en uno.
- La **sexta** línea siempre va a modificar el **HTML** de `#comptador1`  (has dejado un espacio en blanco detrás del **ID** que deberías evitar) por lo que va a sobreescribir lo que habías modificado previamente.

También decirte que aunque el uso de `e.which` es correcto para detectar que tecla del ratón se ha pulsado, esa propiedad no existe si se está usando **Internet Explorer** en cuyo caso tendrías que usar `e.button`.

A continuación pongo un ejemplo funcional para que puedas identificar su uso.

```js
$(function () {
  $("#boto1").mousedown(function(evento){
    let es_derecho;
    evento = evento || window.event;
    
    if ("which" in evento) { // Gecko (Firefox), WebKit (Safari/Chrome) & Opera
        es_derecho = evento.which === 3; 
    }
    else if ("button" in evento) {// IE, Opera 
        es_derecho = evento.button === 2; 
    }
   
    if (es_derecho) {
      alert('Botón derecho pulsado');
    }
    else {
      alert('Botón izquierdo o central pulsado');
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<nav>
  <div id="comptador1" class="caixa"></div> <br /><br /><br />
  <input type="button" value="Clica aquí" id="boto1" class="boto" /> 
</nav>
```

**Referencia:** [Respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2405771/is-right-click-a-javascript-event)